# Keep command output in terminal screen

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm new to Mac, when I use terminal, I found some commands like `git log` behaviours different from Linux.

On Linux, they will print result on screen and exit, leave all result on screen and I can see it when I input another command. Screen after running command like this:

```
$ git log
commit **********
Author: ******
....

$
```

But on Mac, they will print result to a "new screen", after exit, all result will be cleaned so I can't see the previous result. Screen after running command looks like this:

```
$ git log
$
```

Result has been cleared form screen.

Can I change some settings to make it behaviours like linux? Thanks.

Comment: From script or interactive?

Comment: @willWorkForCookies interactive

Comment: What is `$TERM` for both?

Comment: Let's focus on `git` here. If you have similar issues with `grep` (and the answer you get for `git` don't help you to solve them), please ask a new question for this.

Comment: @0942v8653 For linux is xterm, for mac is xterm-256color

Comment: That's kind of odd, I've never seen `grep` use a pager automatically... Usually I have to rerun and pipe into less myself.

Comment: @0942v8653 sorry, i confused the `grep` and `git grep`, so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `git log` is sent to a pager for display, which can be configured via `git config` (variable name is `core.pager`). By default, `less` is used, so you may want to compare the value of `$LESS` on both systems.

Comment: Thanks! On linux `$LESS` is not set and on Mac it has been set to `-R`, means repaint the screen, after put `unset LESS` to `.zshrc` this issue solved. BTW, I confuse the `grep` and `git grep`, sorry for that.